# Copy aspx page across site

Tags: sharepoint-online

What is the best way to copy aspx page in SharePoint Online to another site. The destination option you normally get when copying documents etc does not appear it seems in pages library.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the PnP approach?
It is best described in this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/upload-and-download-a-file-using-pnp-powershell).

Just a heads up, you will have to go over some overhead work of installing PnP PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, this requirement can be fulfilled using Microsoft Flow.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Please refer to this post for more information:
[Copy or Move Site Page from one site to another](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/copy-or-move-site-page-from-one-site-to-another/m-p/255703)

Answer (score 0):

I used this article to help me:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/304986/alternative-save-writebinarydirect-methods-for-cso

It's a hack but still gets the job done if you download the file locally